# Plato's Ion - Can a god inspire a wrong thing?

Tags: plato, socrates

Let's suppose that Socrates does not mock Ion in the dialogue. Socrates states that in every topic which Homer talks about, the master of that topic have the authority to judge whether Homer is right or wrong (538c). Given that according to this dialogue Homer says only what a god inspired him, does Plato in his other dialogues acknowledge that gods can be wrong?

Comment: Sure. Inspiration, whatever its source, does not determine the result, one's own efforts are equally responsible for it. So what is inspired by gods can be wrong even if they are not. Not that it matters here, Homer's gods are wrong all the time for they constantly disagree with each other.

Comment: In Euthyphro, Socrates denies that the gods can disagree with each other. Does he somewhere discuss about the infallibility or fallibility of the gods?

Comment: *Socrates* denies it while Homer portrays it, so his inspiration is clearly fallible.